# Best way to use variables across modules? (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to separate various functions in my program to keep things neat. And I'm getting stuck trying to use variables created in one module in another module. I tried using `global list_of_names` but it wasn't working, and I've read that it's recommended not to do so anyway.

Below is a sample of my code. In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to pass `list_of_names` as a function argument because there are multiple other variables that I need to do this with, aside from the actual arguments that do get passed.

Unfortunately, even if I were to move `read_json` into engine.py, I'd still have the same problem in main.py as I need to reference `list_of_names` there as well.

```
# main.py:
import json
from engine import create_person
def read_json():
    with open('names.json', 'r') as file
        data = json.load(file)
    return data
list_of_names = read_json()
person1 = create_person()
```

```
# engine.py:
from random import choice
def create_person():
    name = choice(list_of_names)
    new_person = {
        'name': name,
        # other keys/values created in similar fashion
    }
    return new_person
```

**EDIT1:**
Here's my new code. To me, this doesn't seem efficient to have to build the parameter list and then deconstruct it inside the function. (I know I'm reusing variable names for this example) Then I have to pass some of those parameters to other functions.

```
# main.py:
import json
from engine import create_person
def read_json():
    with open('names.json', 'r') as file
        data = json.load(file)
    return data

player_id_index = 0
list_of_names = read_json()
person_parameters = [
    list_of_names,
    dict_of_locations,
    player_id_index,
    dict_of_occupations,
    .
    .
    .
]

person1, player_id_index = create_person()
```

```
# engine.py:
from random import choice
def create_person(person_params):
    list_of_names = person_params[0]
    dict_of_locations = person_params[1]
    player_id_index = person_params[2]
    dict_of_occupations = person_params[3]
    .
    .
    .
    attr = person_params[n]

    name = choice(list_of_names)
    location = get_location(dict_of_locations) # a function elsewhere in engine.py
    p_id = player_id_index
    occupation = get_occupation(dict_of_occupations) # a function elsewhere in engine.py

    new_person = {
        'name': name,
        'hometown': location,
        'player id': p_id,
        'occupation': occupation,
        .
        .
        .
    }

    player_id_index += 1
    return new_person, player_id_index
```

Comment: Don't try to use the same variable across multiple modules. You shouldn't even try to use the same variable across multiple functions most of the time. Read up on function arguments and return values, which are almost always the correct way to pass data between functions.

Comment: Summed up with the above, how about some OOP (Object Oriented Programming) structure in your code? It will make your code easier to read, more maintanable and reusable.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski @user2357112 Do you mean something like `create_person(mylist)`? Because as I mentioned it's not practical as I'd have to pass many arguments to the function in this way.

Comment: Define function as `def create_person(list_of_names):`  then pass to the function as an argument `person1 = create_person(list_of_names)`.  If you have a large number of configuration options you would need to pass roll them up into a dictionary (translates nicely from json).  Maybe name it `person_config_options`.  Then the `create_person` function can receive one argument with everything it needs.

Comment: When it said that using `global` is not recommended, it meant *any* type of global variable, not just the keyword. You need to restructure your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should not be relying on shared global state.  If you need to share state encapsulate the state in objects or pass as function arguments.

Regarding your specific problem it looks like you want to assemble random dictionaries from a set of options.  It could be coded like this:

```
from random import choice

person_options = {
   'name': ['fred', 'mary', 'john', 'sarah', 'abigail', 'steve'],
   'health': [6, 8, 12, 15],
   'weapon': ['sword', 'bow'],
   'armor': ['naked', 'leather', 'iron']
}

def create_person(person_options):
    return {k:choice(opts) for k, opts in person_options.items()}

for _ in range(4):
    print create_person(person_options)
```

In action:

```
>>> for _ in range(4):
...     print(create_person(person_options))
...
{'armor': 'naked', 'weapon': 'bow', 'health': 15, 'name': 'steve'}
{'armor': 'iron', 'weapon': 'sword', 'health': 8, 'name': 'fred'}
{'armor': 'iron', 'weapon': 'sword', 'health': 6, 'name': 'john'}
{'armor': 'iron', 'weapon': 'sword', 'health': 12, 'name': 'john'}
```

Note that a dictionary like `{'armor': 'naked', 'weapon': 'bow', 'health': 15, 'name': 'steve'}` looks like it might want to be an object.  A dictionary is a glob of state without any defined behavior.  If you make a class to house this state the class can grow methods that act on that state.  Of course, explaining all this could make this answer really really long.  For now, just realize that you should move away from having shared state that any old bit of code can mess with.  A little bit of discipline on this will make your code much easier to refactor later on.

---

This addresses your edited question:

```
from random import choice
from itertools import count
from functools import partial

person_options = {
   'name': partial(
         choice, ['fred', 'mary', 'john', 'sarah', 'abigail', 'steve']),
   'location': partial(
         get_location, {'heaven':1, 'hell':2, 'earth':3}),
   'player id': count(1).next
}

def create_person(person_options):
    return {k:func() for k, func in person_options.items()}
```

However, we are now way beyond the scope of your original question and getting into specifics that won't be helpful to anyone other than you.  Such questions are better asked on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes that is part of what I'm doing. I'm also trying to issue a unique numeric `id` to each person created. To do that in this way, I'd have to pass an `id_iterator` to the function each time, iterate it, then return it back. Also, not everything is a random choice, so on the main.py side I need to build the list, then on the engine.py side I have to assign each item in the list to a variable. It just doesn't seem efficient to have to constantly do that across multiple functions that do similar things as my `create_player`.

Comment: Based on @Steven_Rumbalski comment, I [created a thread on CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159360/football-game-simulation)